# SilverStripe hosted on IIS causes permission errors on cache_dir

Tags: php, iis, zend-framework, silverstripe

We have SilverStripe (2.4.x) running on IIS because the client needs Windows logon information. This in turn is available only via IIS. Making IIS to proxy this information to a Linux server isn't a possibility (at least not yet). PHP has `impersonate` on.

The error is `[User Error] Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir is not writable`. This comes and goes randomly as users surf around. Usually the file in question is a template cache file.

To fix this we've tried the following:

1. Modified the logic behind `cache_dir` path generation. It now includes the username of the impersonated user: `silverstripe-cache/myuser`. This made the errors less frequent but they still exist.
2. Set cache lifetime to -1: `SS_Cache::set_cache_lifetime('default', -1, 100);`. This still writes to files (but doesn't use them, I suppose).

The possible reasons I've found relate to [IIS caching the files PHP tries to write to](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28093/iis-problem-with-drupal-update-manager-update-failed-directories-are-locked/142361#142361). Is this the correct reason or should we search for the problem somewhere else?

If what I've found is the real cause is there anything we can do? Can the Zend_Cache be disabled fully so that it doesn't try to write to files at all?

Comment: Is the Silverstripe cache folder in the Windows "Temp" directory or in the root of the site? (if you create a folder called "silverstripe-cache" in the root of the site, that is used for the cache).

Comment: silverstripe-cache is inside the project folder.

Comment: How much traffic is on the site when the errors happen? Is it just one user going across to different pages or dozens of users at once? Right now I'm leaning to the reason you found. There is likely a way to get around the cache if we have to, will look into it more tonight. :)

Comment: It seems totally random. We haven't received any error reports though after disabling `impersonate`. But for some odd reason I cannot believe this to be right.

Comment: If your issue is still happening, there is a possibility you can use `Object::useCustomClass` to switch out `SS_Cache` for your own class which exposes the same functions but does nothing with them. However, there is a chance that templates will not load properly as it uses the same method.

Comment: Not to mention the YAML config cache won't work if you disable `SS_Cache` or `Zend_Cache`.

Comment: So it really is difficult to get rid of the cache... I think I'll just mark this answered in a month or so if nothing comes up from the client.